# Orden de lista descendente Python

Tags: python-3.x

Hola Tengo una duda sobre este código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me imprime esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es por que repite títulos y en que se basa para el orden reverse al ser valores literales.

Comment: Porque estás aplicando `reverse()` en cada iteración. Saca `reverse()` y ponlo antes del `for`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, ya funciona.

Comment: recuerda corregir tu consulta y cerrar la pregunta usando el codigo con el comentario de canddi moe.

Answer (score 0):

Primero recordarte que para realizar consultas tienes que copiar el código sobre el que quieres realizar la consulta, de lo contrario tenemos que volver a copiarlo entero para mostrarte la respuesta.

Creo que lo que quieres poner en el segundo for es lo siguiente:

```
print("su orden descendente es")
for i in reversed(canciones):
    print(i)
```

Como lo haces tu, das la vuelta al array en cada iteración y por tanto te coge la primera, la penúltima, la tercera...

Un saludo!